# How to arrange array spirally but anticlockwise - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var sampleArray = [[1,2,3,4],
                  [5,6,7,8],
                  [9,10,11,12],
                  [13,14,15,16],
                  [17,18,19,20]
                  ];


function printSpiral(myArray, clockwise) {
  //anti-clockwise:
  //1,5,9,13,17, 18,19,20, 16,12,8,4, 3,2, 6,10,14, 15,11,7


   if(!clockwise) {

     myArray = transpose(myArray)

     //console.log(myArray)
  }

  var rows = myArray.length;

  var cols = myArray[0].length;
  if(rows <= 1) {
    return myArray[0];
  }

  if(cols === 0) {
    return myArray[0];
  }



      var firstRow = myArray[0]; 
      var newMatrix = [];
      var newRow;
      var rowIdx;
      var colIdx = myArray[1].length - 1;


  for(colIdx; colIdx >=0; colIdx--) {

      newRow = [];

     for(rowIdx = 1; rowIdx < rows; rowIdx++) {
       newRow.push(myArray[rowIdx][colIdx])
       //console.log(newRow)
     }

    newMatrix.push(newRow)
  }


  //console.log(newMatrix)

  firstRow.push.apply(firstRow,printSpiral(newMatrix));

  //console.log(firstRow)

  return firstRow


  //return newMatrix


  // Spiral Order
  // 1,2,3,4, 8,12,16,20, 19,18,17, 13,9,5, 6,7, 11,15, 14, 10

}

var result = printSpiral(sampleArray, false);

console.log(result)
```

I am trying to print the array spirally but anticlockwise. I have tried to transpose the matrix but it doesn't help how do I print the following array.

//1,5,9,13,17, 18,19,20, 16,12,8,4, 3,2, 6,10,14, 15,11,7

Please help

Comment: i am not sure about your test cases but you can do something like that http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/

Comment: is it always 4X4 matrix or could be 6X6?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can be 6*6 also

Answer (score 2):

Its not very elegant, but here's the juiste of the algorithm:

```
<script>
var array = [[1,2,3,4],
             [5,6,7,8],
             [9,10,11,12],
             [13,14,15,16],
             [17,18,19,20]];


function spiral(array) {
    var list = []; 

    var array = array[0].map(function(col, i) { 
        return array.map(function(row) { 
            return row[i] 
        })
    });

    list.push(array[0]);
    array.shift()

    while (typeof array[0] !== 'undefined'){

        var array = array[0].map(function(col, i) { 
            return array.map(function(row) { 
                return row[i] 
            })
        });

        array.reverse();
        list.push(array[0]);
        array.shift();
    }
    return list
}

var list = spiral(array)
document.writeln(list); 
</script>
```

basically the idea is as follows, a rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise is done with a transpose and flip. then we pop the top row, and do it again.
so we transpose the array, array.reverse to flip it, push our row into a list, array.shift to pop the row, repeat.

Also the main benefit of this method is that it wont care what the dimensions of your array are. they can be asymmetric or not.